# Go - trying to create a .pgm file but end up with a binary file

Tags: file-io, go

I'm reading a pgm-file in order to apply some filter to it and rewrite the result to a new pgm-file. However, I always end up with a binary file (vim doesn't show the values but stuff like ^G ^0 ^K etc, the file-command tells me it's a data file and imagemagick can't open the file)

The code where I write to the file looks like this:

```
fd,err := os.Create(filename)
wr := bufio.NewWriter(fd)
//img is of type [][]int and holds the values to be written
str := "P2\n" + filename + "\n" + string(len(img[0])) + ...
if _,err := wr.WriteString(outStr); err != nil {..}
```

and then some more of that in a loop where I go through the img array.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string(len(img[0]))` doesn't do what you're trying to do here. You need `strconv.Itoa`

`string(len(img[0]))` is creating a single character string containing whichever character is the Unicode code point for `len(img[0])` (see [the spec section on conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions))